# Two wires of same material have diameters in ratio 2:1. If they are stretched by same force, what will be their elongation ratio?

Tags: solid-state-physics

I am preparing for a test and this question comes up. And I can't solve it. Although the answer is given in the key as 1:4 but how do I get to that? What formula do I have to use? Two wires of same material have diameters in ratio 2:1. If they are stretched by same force, what will be their elongation ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of elastic modulus is:

$$E=\frac{FL_0}{A_0\Delta L}$$

Where:
$$\lambda=\frac{\Delta L}{L_0}=\frac{F}{EA_0}$$

... is the elongation.

Where:
$$A_0=\frac{\pi D^2}{4}$$

With the latter two expressions find the ratio $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_1}$ for any ratio $\frac{D_1}{D_2}$, for any force $F$.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that this holds only for idealised Hookean materials, doesn't it?

Comment: @Sanya: yes but that is 'in the spirit' of the question.

Comment: granted and it was no criticism at all :) your answer is really clear and easy to understand.

Comment: @gert please solve using the given values. :)

Comment: @Shujaahmeddar: please insert third equation into second one to get an expression for $\lambda=f(D)$.

Comment: I dont understand it man 

Comment: Okay but what about the value of f?

Comment: Work out an expression for $\lambda_1$, for $D_1=2D_2$. Then work out an expression for $\lambda_2$, for $D_2$. Divide both expressions to get $\lambda_1/\lambda_2$.